# Ecto: select fields from two tables

Tags: join, select, orm, elixir, ecto

I have following function:

```
  def get(fields_from_book, fields_from_author) do
    Books
    |> join(:left, [b], a in Author, on: b.id == a.book_id)
    |> select([b, a], fields_from_book, fields_from_author)
    |> Repo.all()
```

I am interested in line `select([b, a], fields_from_book, fields_from_author)`. Is there any way in Ecto to specify two arrays of fields from two tables separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with a help of custom macro. The approach would be more or less the same as in [`Ecto.Query.dynamic/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#dynamic/2).

```rb
def query(fields_from_book, fields_from_author) do
  from b in Book,
    join: a in Author,
    on: on: b.id == a.book_id,
    select: ??? # {b.title, a.name}
```

Now we need to build the select expression with a macro. Let’s see what do we expect to get back.

```rb
iex> quote do: {a.name, b.title, b.price}
#⇒ {:{}, [],
#   [
#     {{:., [], [{:a, [], Elixir}, :name]}, [no_parens: true], []},
#     {{:., [], [{:b, [], Elixir}, :title]}, [no_parens: true], []},
#     {{:., [], [{:b, [], Elixir}, :price]}, [no_parens: true], []}
#   ]}
```

OK, let’s implement this (below I assume the fields list is passed as a compile-time literal, e. g. the list.)

```rb
defmacrop select_many(books, authors) do
  all =
    Enum.map(books,
      &{{:., [], [{:b, [], Elixir}, &1]}, [no_parens: true], []}) ++ 
    Enum.map(authors,
      &{{:., [], [{:b, [], Elixir}, &1]}, [no_parens: true], []})

  quote do: {unquote_splicing(all)}
end
```

and use it as:

```rb
def query(fields_from_book, fields_from_author) do
  from b in Book,
    join: a in Author,
    on: on: b.id == a.book_id,
    select: select_many(fields_from_book, fields_from_author)
```

Untested, but it should work.

---

Excerpt from [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) docs: [Defining custom functions using macros and fragment](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1-defining-custom-functions-using-macros-and-fragment).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I started to generalize this macro and changed signature to:
`defmacrop select_many({table1, table1_f}, {table2, table2_f}) do` it works fine when I call it like `select([a, b], select_many({:a, [:code, :id,]}, {:b, [:status]}))` but when I create variables and pass lists as variables it stops working.
What can be wrong here?

Comment: When you pass a variable, the macro still receives an AST. You would need to `quote` / `unquote` to get to the context of the caller. How macros work in general is not a question that might be answered in comments here, sorry for that. I explicitly stated this answer would work if and only if “the fields list is passed as a compile-time literal.”

Comment: You might try `quote do: unquote(table1).unquote(table1_f)` but I am not sure and I cannot test it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it seems, I come up with a simple solution:

```
fields_book =  [:code, :title_code, :publication_date,]
fields_author = [:name]

Book
|> join(:left, [b], a in assoc(b, :author))
|> select([b, a], merge(map(b, ^fields_book), map(a, ^fields_author)))
|> Repo.all()
```